# .NET assembly in current domain cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file-io

I have a project I am working that will search all loaded assemblies for any class that implements a certain interface. Then it will create an instance of that class and invoke a method of the interface. The code ran great on simple projects in testing environments. At the heart of it is the following function:

```
    public static List<Type> GetLoadedTypes(Type targetType)
    {
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => targetType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();
        return types;
    }
```

I have another project that inserted this code into and the LINQ query fails because one of the assemblies in the domain cannot be found.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder, Version=1.0.51206.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I don't directly reference this assembly in any of my projects. How can I find out which assembly references it? How did the assembly even get into the domain if it cannot be found?

**EDIT:**
I am using Enterprise Library in the project but I am already referencing the Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll. Apparently there is a difference between the two assemblies. Is that correct?

Thanks!
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Assembly Binding Log Viewer" (Fuslogvw.exe) that belongs to the dotnet2.0sdk (maybe also in later edition) . If logging is enabled it can show you wich assemblies are loaded and which assembly caused it to load.

For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I havent been able to get this to produce any results. Does it work for .net 3.5? Logging is not enabled in the settings section (all of the fields there are disabled). Do you know how to get them enabled? Googling a few different terms to find out didnt turn anything up.

Comment: You have to set a custom log location, otherwise it doesn't seem to work:  http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2007/11/debugging-with-fusion-logger.html

Comment: this did the trick! fuslogvw.exe showed me which assembly was loading the missing assembly and it turns out that i didnt need a reference to that offending assmbly in my project anyway. removed the reference and everything is working! thanks!

Comment: after i got fuslogvw up and running, i realized that I could create a registry key to add the log message to the asp.net error page:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog (DWORD) set to 1

Now I also finally understand that error message! Two birds, one stone.

Answer (score 1):

This is used by Microsoft's **Unity**. Copy the DLL to your bin at the time of build (using script, ...) or add a reference.

---

**Update**

In order to find out, you can add AppDomain's [AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event and check RequestingAssembly property in the arguments.

---

**Update 2**

OK, here is how I would have approached it:

- Use sysinternal's procmon to monitor your executable. You will see name of the file (objectbuilder2) popping up with a lot of FILE NOT FOUND events in there. See where it is looking for it, you need it to be there. I think DLL is being loaded in a different location
- Make sure this specific version of the DLL exists

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 so unfortunately the RequestingAssembly property isn't available to me. Also, see my update on the original question. I am not using Unity, but I am using Enterprise Library. I have the ObjectBuilder2.dll assembly referenced but it doesnt make any difference for resolving this assembly.

Comment: @Jeff, this has been available since version 1.1 so you can definitely use it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: Right. I was able to overload the event but the event args dont have the RequestingAssmbly property. From the MSDN page you originally linked to: "Beginning with the .NET Framework version 4, the ResolveEventArgs..::.RequestingAssembly property returns the assembly that requested the assembly load that could not be resolved." Inspecting the object in the debugger confirms that there is no RequestingAssembly in 3.5. In 3.5, ResolveEventArgs only has a Name property.

Comment: OK. I have given another few points, hope it helps you to figure it out.